# How can a execute a query in JSP on text change of input box

Tags: java, jsp, text, input

Now i am doing this code which is working on submit button click.

```
<%@page import="java.sql.CallableStatement"%>
<%@page import="javax.imageio.ImageIO"%>
<%@page import="java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.awt.image.BufferedImage"%>
<%@page import="java.io.InputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="connectionss.Connectionss"%>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<form  action="ShowUSerInfo.jsp" method="post">                                     
        <input type="text"  name="tagID">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" name="submit" >          
</form>

             <%
             String TAGID="";
             String y=request.getParameter("submit");

                 if("Search".equals(y))
                    {
                TAGID = request.getParameter("tagID");
                out.println(TAGID);


                    String GetUserpass = "{call sp_USerInfoByTagID(?)}";
                    //Connection conn = Connection.GetConnection();
                    CallableStatement cs;
                    cs =  Connectionss.GetConnection().prepareCall(GetUserpass);
                    cs.setString(1,TAGID);
               %>

                    <table border="1">
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>last Name Name</th>
                    <th>Student ID</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                      <th>NIC</th>

                    <% 
                        ResultSet rs1;
                        rs1=cs.executeQuery();
                        while(rs1.next()){

                            String UserName=rs1.getString("fId_FirstName");

                            String UserID= rs1.getString("fId_User_UniversityID");
                            String Adress = rs1.getString("fId_Address"); 
                            String NIC = rs1.getString("fId_NIC");
                            String lastName = rs1.getString("fId_LastName");

                            %>                    

                <tr >

                <td><span style="color:red;"><%= UserName %></span></td>
                <td> <span style="color:red;"><%= lastName %></span></td>
                <td><span style="color:red;"><%= UserID %></span></td>
                <td><span style="color:red;"><%= Adress %></span></td>
                <td><span style="color:red;"><%= NIC %></span></td>

                </tr>

                </table>

           <%}} %>                    

</body>
</html>
```

But i want to execute this code when text changes on input box. Basically text box is getting value from NFC cards. so when i tap my NFC card on Reader value is transfer to text box and at this time i want to execute my sql query that will take the user information against TAGID.

Comment: you can try using scripting-element, while text box text change, submit form again and again. Let me know if any query.

Comment: My tag id is always of 14 digits which contain both number and alphabet like 47454598as89s6 . so the jquery code should execute my sql query when 14 digit tag is in input box

Answer (score 1):

since jsp is server side you'll need to collect the input on client and make a ajax call.

```
<form  action="ShowUSerInfo.jsp" method="post">
       <input type="text" id="text"  name="tagID">
       <input type="submit" value="Search" name="submit" >
</form>
    <div id="#res></div>
```

javascript :

```
   $('#text').change(function(e){
      $.ajax({url: "someurl", success: function(result){
             $("#res").html(result);
          }});
        });
  });
```

Comment: My tag id is always of 14 digits which contain both number and alphabet  like **47454598as89s6** . so the jquery code should execute my sql query when 14 digit tag is in input box.

Comment: Like when we put activation code on viber it direclty go to next activity without pressing submitiing button

Answer (score -1):

this will perfectly work in your case,

Let's say our HTML looks something like,

```
<form>
    <input id="txt" type="text" name="name"/>
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="change"/>
</form>
```

Java-Script like,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#txt').keypress(function(e){
            ontextchange();
          });
        $('#txt').keyup(function(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 8)
               {
                  //if user erase from text-box then comes here...
               }
           });

        function ontextchange(){
        //do whatever while text change, i.e. ajax call or something else...
        }
    });
```